# How to dynamically change mysql data on the Treeview in python tkinter GUI

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, treeview

I am new to python and I can't figure out how to dynamically change MySQL data on the treeview in python GUI? In my code, some 'dummy' data is imported and saved into MySQL server/database and then python GUI shows the data in a treeview. If I need to update the data in the treeview, I have to stop the code and run it again. After doing this, the latest collected data shows up in the treeview, but it is still not changing live. Here is my code:

```
        from tkinter import *
        from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
        from tkinter import messagebox
        import mysql.connector
        import serial
        import time
        from datetime import datetime
        from threading import Thread
        from numba.core.tracing import event
        
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="engineer",database="demo")
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        
        
        def send_info(idNumber, timestampStr):
            import mysql.connector
            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="engineer", database="demo")
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            sqlFormula = "INSERT INTO dailyAttendance (idnumber,time) VALUES (%s,%s)"
            idnumber = [(idNumber, timestampStr)]
            mycursor.executemany(sqlFormula, idnumber)
            mydb.commit()
            return 0
        
        def getSerial():
            ser = serial.Serial('com5', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
            while(True):
                try:
                    if (ser.in_waiting):
                        data = str(ser.read_until(b'\r').decode('ascii'))
                        ser.flushInput()
                        datalist = data.split(';')
                        col2 = datalist[1]
                        rssivalue = int(col2[5:8])
                        if rssivalue >= -26:
                            col3 = datalist[2]
                            idNumber = col3[5:20]
                            print(idNumber)
                            dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
                            timestampStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S)")
                            send_info(idNumber, timestampStr)
                except Exception as ex:
                    print(ex)
                time.sleep(1)
        
        def mainGUI():
            master = Tk()
            master.geometry("800x700")  # (widthxheight)
            master.title("Graphical User Interface")
            topFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(master, text="Student Attendance")
            topFrame.pack(fill="both", expand="yes", padx=20, pady=10)
            table = ttk.Treeview(topFrame, columns=(1, 2), show="headings", height="2")
            table.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
            table.heading(1, text="Tag ID")
            table.heading(2, text="Timestamp")
            treescrolly = ttk.Scrollbar(topFrame, orient="vertical", command=table.yview)
            treescrolly.pack(side="right", fill="y")
            table.configure(yscrollcommand=treescrolly.set)
        
            def update():
                mycursor.execute("SELECT idnumber, time from dailyattendance")
                mysqldata = mycursor.fetchall()
                table.delete(*table.get_children())
                for row in mysqldata:
                    table.insert('', 'end', values= (row[0], row[1]))
                master.after(500, update)
        
            update()
            master.mainloop()
        
        Thread(target= getSerial).start()
        Thread(target= mainGUI).start()
```

I have tried using `.after()` in my `update()` function as seen in my code but treeview doesn't update live. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You better check whether the insertion of data into table succeeds or fails.  Or check whether you have retrieved data from the table actually.

Comment: Notice that you used `dailyAttendance` in `INSERT` statement, but `dailyattendance` in `SELECT` statement.  If your MySQL server is case-sensitive on table name, then it may be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try that